# Tag column values contained in other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have the following table as an input :

```
+-----------+--------------+----------------+------------------+
| tableName | duplicate_Id |   Index_name   |   Column_List    |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+------------------+
| foo       |            1 |    foo_index_1 | fafa, fifi, fufu |
| foo       |            2 |    foo_index_2 | fafa, fifi       |
| bar       |            1 |    bar_index_1 | bubu, bebe       |
| bar       |            2 |    bar_index_2 | bubu             |
| bar       |            3 |    bar_index_3 | bebe             |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+------------------+
```

I want to know for each row of each table if its *Column_List* value is contained within another row of that same table (Is considered contained if the pattern matchs X%, not only %X%).

As a desired output I would get :

```
+-----------+--------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+
| tableName | duplicate_Id |   Index_name   |   Column_List    | Contained |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+
| foo       |            1 |    foo_index_1 | fafa, fifi, fufu | false     |
| foo       |            2 |    foo_index_2 | fafa, fifi       | true      | (true, contained within id 1 of same table)
| bar       |            1 |    bar_index_1 | bubu, bebe       | false     |
| bar       |            2 |    bar_index_2 | bubu             | true      | (true, contained within id 1 of same table)
| bar       |            3 |    bar_index_3 | bebe             | false     | (false, 'bebe%' doesn't match 'bubu,bebe'
+-----------+--------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+
```

I would really appreciate some help or clues here.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Also *why* are you storing delimited data? YOu really should be fixing your design.

Comment: I'm not storing this data in my database, this is the result that I got building a CTE but I don't know how to keep on from here. I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Then why are you creating delimited results? It would be easier if they weren't. If the above dataset is created from another dataset, perhaps we should see what your data looks like *before* you change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `EXISTS` and the operator `LIKE`:

```
select t.*,
  case when exists (
      select 1 from tablename
      where Column_list like t.Column_list + ',%'
    ) then 'true'
    else 'false'
  end Contained
from tablename t
```

I assume that you want to match only the starting of the column.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b63d5f77b85f7b1b7e0c26a49391d920).
Results:

```
> tableName | duplicate_Id | Index_name  | Column_List      | Contained
> :-------- | -----------: | :---------- | :--------------- | :--------
> foo       |            1 | foo_index_1 | fafa, fifi, fufu | false    
> foo       |            2 | foo_index_2 | fafa, fifi       | true     
> bar       |            1 | bar_index_1 | bubu, bebe       | false    
> bar       |            2 | bar_index_2 | bubu             | true     
> bar       |            3 | bar_index_3 | bebe             | false
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue. It needs some tweaking to filter on the tableName column but I get the idea from here.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . This would seem to do what you want:

```
select i.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from input i2
                          where concat(', ', i2.column_list, ', ') like concat('%, ', i.column_list, ', %') and
                                i2.column_list <> i.column_list
                         )
             then 'true' else 'false'
        end) as flag
from input i;
```

Note that if you are interpreting that string as a list of elements, **then you should fix your data model**.  Do not store lists as strings.  SQL has a great way of storing lists -- it is called a "table".